# Laplace PDE on Disk - Poisson's Formula

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

[image]

After separating the variables, I ended up with a general solution of the form:
$$u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n[A_n\cos(n\theta)+B_nsin(n\theta)]$$
How exactly do I use the boundary condition $u(\alpha,\theta)=1+3\sin(\theta)$ to determine the coefficients?

Comment: This is not the general solution for this problem, it should involve Bessel functions. Did you switch to polar coordinates to express the Poisson equation?

Comment: @Paul I think you're thinking of Helmholtz. Laplace in polars is as the OP has it, providing $u$ is CTS at $r=0$.

Comment: yes, I expressed the Poisson equation, separated $r$ and $\theta$ and ignored solutions of the form $cr^{-n}$ because they're not finite at the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution can be written as
$$
u(r,\theta)=\frac{A_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_nr^n\cos nx+B_n r^n \sin nx.
$$
Hence
$$
1+\sin 3\theta=\frac{A_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\alpha^n\cos nx+B_n \alpha^n \sin nx.
$$
Directly comparing the coefficients on the left and on the right you have
$$
A_0=2,A_n=0,n\geq 1, B_3\alpha^3=1, B_n=0,n\neq 3.
$$
Hence your solution is
$$
u(r,\theta)=1+\frac{1}{\alpha^3}r^3\sin 3\theta.
$$

*Added:* Ups, I made a typo and considered $\sin 3\theta$ instead of $3\sin \theta$. But hopefully the idea is clear and you can finish your problem yourself.

Comment: Thank you! So, using the Poisson's Formula to determine the coefficients is a superfluous and complex thing to do?

Comment: Your questions does not make any sense because nowhere in your question nor my answer you can find Poisson formula.

Comment: That's my point. We haven't used Poisson's formula. Wouldn't it be unnecessary to use for solving this example, since the boundary condition is already a sine series?